# what does the fdisk output mean

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, fdisk

What does `sudo fdisk -l` mean?
This is the output. I installed Windows7 and Ubuntu. Using `fdisk`, I get four partitions. What does each partition mean? Which one is Ubuntu? Which one is Windows7?

[image: The results from sudo fdisk -l]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo fdisk -l` lists all the partitions on all your storages partitioned with `msdos` partitioning label.

I think that,

`/dev/sda1` is active primary partition.

This partition has **Windows 7** boot loader.

`/dev/sda2` is primary partition formatted as *NTFS*.

This partition has **Windows 7**.

`/dev/sda3` is primary partition formatted as *swap space*.

This is a swap space used by **Ubuntu**.

`/dev/sda4` is primary partition formatted as a linux file system(ex: *ext2/ext3/ext4*...).

As result,

`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` is used for **Windows 7**,

`/dev/sda4` is the /(root filesystem) for **Ubuntu**,

`/dev/sda3` is *swap space* for **Ubuntu**. Swap space is a space on a hard disk used as the virtual memory extension of a computer's real memory.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo fdisk -l` lists all the partitions on all your storage devices connected and recognized.

Your `/dev/sda2` is Windows 7 and `/dev/sda4` is Ubuntu. You can infer that from the type and size of the blocks as follows:

Windows 7 needs NTFS and you have only two partitions that are NTFS partitions. Now, windows will need more than at 102 MB for its partition so, `/dev/sda1` cannot be the C: drive, it is the boot loader for Windows 7.

Now `/dev/sda3` is the swap partition and ubuntu needs ext partitions for it, so the only partition that remains is `/dev/sda4`.

In summary:

- `/dev/sda1` is the Windows boot loader
- `/dev/sda2` is the Windows C: drive
- `/dev/sda3` is the swap partition
- `/dev/sda4` is Ubuntu's `/` folder

Comment: since there is only one best answer, I gave it to the answer provided earlier. Your answer is also great. Thanks

Comment: @tqjustc Give it to the one who is most helpful, and if they are the same, the earlier one usually wins.